# Python Opencv Image Stitching Creates Empty file

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am using Python 3 and when running this code i end up with an empty file named "result.jpg". Would appreciate any help, thanks;

```
import cv2
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(True)
foo = cv2.imread("one.jpg")
bar = cv2.imread("two.jpg")
result = stitcher.stitch((foo,bar))
cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", result[1])
```

I have no errors showing, just the empty file output. Is there an error if the function fails to stitch the images together?

Comment: what does `result[0]` return?

Answer (score 0):

If the stitched image is empty it probably means there was an error.

Notice that result[0] returns the status of the panorama stitching.
According to the status you can understand what error was encountered.

From the documentation:

```
Status { 
  OK = 0, 
  ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS = 1, 
  ERR_HOMOGRAPHY_EST_FAIL = 2, 
  ERR_CAMERA_PARAMS_ADJUST_FAIL = 3 
}
```